# getting an error when trying to print out a structure

Tags: c, struct

I want to store the inputs in a structure and then arrange them in alphabetical order and then print them out, but it is giving this error. I did not include the other half of the code as I don't think it is relevant

```
./main.c:32:30: error: subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector
              Pupils[i].DM213[i] + Pupils[i].DM214 + Pupils[i].DM215)/8;
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
./main.c:34:50: error: use of undeclared identifier 'compare'
qsort(Pupils, PupilAmount, sizeof(struct Pupil), compare);
                                                 ^
2 errors generated.
make: *** [Makefile:10: main] Error 1
exit status 2
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  //Aquires how many Pupils will be inputted
    int PupilAmount;
  printf("How many Pupils would you like to input?\n");
  scanf("%d", &PupilAmount);
//Creates structure and variable arrays for each module and Lastname
struct Pupil {
    char Lastnames[20];
    int DM210;
    int DM211;
    int DM212;
    int DM213;
    int DM214;
    int DM215;
};
//will run this process and obtain overall percentage results for as many Pupils are on file
    int arr[PupilAmount];
    printf("Would you like to read from a file? (y/n)\n");
    char input;
    scanf(" %c", &input);
    if (input == 'y') {
      FILE *fp;
      fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
     struct Pupil Pupils[PupilAmount];
for (int i = 0; i < PupilAmount; i++) {
    fscanf(fp, "%19s %d %d %d %d %d %d", 
           Pupils[i].Lastnames, 
           &Pupils[i].DM210, &Pupils[i].DM211, &Pupils[i].DM212,
           &Pupils[i].DM213, &Pupils[i].DM214, &Pupils[i].DM215);
    arr[i] = (Pupils[i].DM210*2 + Pupils[i].DM211*2 + Pupils[i].DM212 +
              Pupils[i].DM213[i] + Pupils[i].DM214 + Pupils[i].DM215)/8;
//Sorts the Pupils in alphabetical order
qsort(Pupils, PupilAmount, sizeof(struct Pupil), compare);
//Prints the results

printf("Lastname  Overall Percentage Mark  DM210  DM211  DM212  DM213  DM214  DM215\n");
  
  for (int i = 0; i < PupilAmount; i++) 
    printf("%s \t %12.1d \t %12.1d \t %4.1d \t %4.1d \t %4.1d \t %4.1d \t %4.1d \n"),Pupils[PupilAmount] ;}   
fclose(fp);}
return 0;}
```

Comment: The error message (use of undeclared identifier 'compare') is really clear. To be able to use a function in any way, you must first *declare* it. Didn't your beginners books, tutorials or classes teach you that? Actually, not only are you missing a declaration, you don't even have a *definition* (implementation) of any such function. Why did you think using an unknown function like that would work? What kind of teaching materials have you been using to learn C?

Comment: What is `DM213[i]` supposed to mean, when `DM213` is an `int` field?

Comment: i think i did it its because its a variable array?

Comment: No, `Pupils` is an array. `Pupils[i]` is a `struct Pupil` object. And `Pupils[i].DM213` is a single `int` value. You can't use indexes with plain `int` values. So that error is pretty clear as well.

Comment: You don't need to repeat the `[i]`. You already subscripted with `Pupils[i]`, that's enough.